# Guardar el total anual de todos los ingresos

Tags: php, mysql

Hola chicos seré breve y preciso con esta pregunta, quiero  guardar en mi tabla de mysql (`total_anual`) que contiene las siguientes celdas: `year, anual;`  y `guadar` el total anual de mi tabla (`factura`) que contiene las siguientes celdas: `precio, día,  mes, year, fecha`

Comment: podrías agregar lo que haz intentado hasta el momento?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
INSERT INTO total_anual
SELECT year(fecha), sum(precio)
FROM factura
GROUP BY year(fecha);
```

Para esto, he utilizado:
1. year( ): Obtiene el anno de un campo fecha.
2. sum( ): Sumariza una columna.
3. GROUP BY: Agrupa los registros por un campo en específico.

Además de hacer un "INSERT SELECT", si quisieras almacenar solamente un anno en específico agrega después del "FROM factura" lo siguiente:

```
WHERE year(fecha) = 2018
```